# How do we perform recursive query on apache drill

Tags: sql, apache-drill

In apache drill how do we perform recursive queries using CTE with clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Drill does not support recursive queries. [Usage Notes](https://drill.apache.org/docs/with-clause/#usage-notes) section:

> `Drill can only reference a table defined by a WITH clause subquery in the scope of the SELECT query that the WITH clause begins. For example, you can reference such a table in the FROM clause of a subquery in the SELECT list, WHERE clause, or HAVING clause. You cannot use a WITH clause in a subquery and reference its table in the FROM clause of the main query or another subquery.`

Try rewriting your query without recursion. There was also a discussion on dev [mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/drill-user/201507.mbox/%3CFDC2689B-20EA-49BA-A214-5B52258C9ECD@gmail.com%3E), it might have useful suggestions or workarounds.